# Time taken for Brute Force Attack on DES

Tags: des, brute-force-attack

An attacker is equipped with a computer that performs 10 trillion (10<sup>13</sup>) DES decryptions per second, what is the average time required, in hours, for a brute force attacker to break DES? Key size is 56 bits.

I tried 2<sup>56</sup>/10<sup>13</sup> divided by 3600 but the answer is incorrect.

Comment: $2^{56}/10^{13}$ \[as in the [original statement](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/revisions/80367/1)\] is incorrect for three reasons: a) it does not account for the _"average"_ word of the problem statement. b) it does not account for the _"hours"_ word of the problem statement [update: that part got fixed]. c) nitpick: it does not account for the _"time"_ word of the problem statement, for lack of unit: if it not asked _how many_ hours are required... Second rule of sucess in exams: in a good problem, every word counts (first rule is: attend).

Comment: Is 'Bruce Force' [done by comedic Australians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bruces_sketch)?

Answer (score 2):

You got $2^{56}$ different keys and the attacker can test $10^{13}$ keys per second.

In the worst case, the last tested key is the solution. For that you need $2^{56} / 10^{13} \approx 7205$ sec. -> around $2$ hours.

In the best case, the first tested key is the solution. This takes about 1 second.

On Average you need to test half of the keys. That means: $0.5 * (2^{56} / 10^{13}) \approx 1$ hour.

Comment: Redo your calculations, $2^{56} / 10^{13} \not\approx 8796093022208$

Comment: also if he can test $10^{13}$ keys/second how come it takes a full second when the first key tested is the correct key?

Comment: That's why i wrote "about 1 sec." You can lower that time to nearly 0 sec. But for calculating the average case, it makes no difference.